# In the movie Sunshine, lack of air becomes an issue

Tags: sunshine

In the movie Sunshine, the explosive package is in a vast chamber attached to the shield, presumably filled with air. Why was oxygen deprivation an issue earlier in the film? A football team could have been practicing in there for a week and not run out of air.

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunshine_(2007_film) instead.